# Definition of Normal Bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I'm reading Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Bott and Tu. I reached the point where the book defines the normal bundle of a submanifold and uses the tubular neighborhood theorem. I can't for the life of me understand the definition. The book uses the following definition:

> If $ S $ is a submanifold in $ M $, then normal bundle $ N $ of $ S $ in $ M $ is the vector bundle on $ S $ defined by the exact sequence $$ 0\rightarrow T_{S} \rightarrow \left.T_{M}\right|_{S} \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0, $$
>   where $ \left.T_{M}\right|_{S} $ is the restriction of the tangent bundle of $ M $ to $ S$.

The book doesn't explain what the maps are. Surprisingly I could not find a clear definition on the web either. I think $ T_{S} $ is mapped to corresponding vectors in $ \left.T_{M}\right|_{S} $, but I don't know how to make this map well-defined. Some PDFs online suggest using adapted charts on $ M $ in which $ S $ is defined by the vanishing of a fixed number of coordinates. I have no idea what the other map in the exact sequence is.

Can you please show me how to $ N $ is defined, how it gets its topology and becomes a bundle on $ S $?

I don't know Riemannian Geometry, so please don't use it.

As a side note, I found the book to be terse. Everyone swears by how clear it is, but I find it missing a lot of details and it has very few examples. I studied Hatcher's Algebraic Topology and Tu's Introduction to Manifold, so I think I'm prepared.

Thank you. I have been banging my head against this for most of the day.

Comment: Well $T_S\rightarrow T_M|S$ is just the inclusion map of vector bundles. A tangent vector to $S$ is a vector is $M$.

Comment: So $N$ is the codomain of this map.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus You mean cokernel, not codomain.

Comment: Oops..yeah, its the cokernal, the quotient of the $T_M|S$ by the image of $T_S$

Comment: Thank you both. The book doesn't define a quotient operation on bundles. How does it work?

Comment: @Peter: it's the pointwise quotient on fibers. You can use local trivializations to figure out how this gives a bundle.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks. This is easy once a few details are spelled out. I can't believe I wasted a day on this. :(

Comment: I think it's useful to note that you will need a metric to define the normal bundle properly as a subbundle of the tangent bundle $TM$. You can do this by pulling $S$ with the zero section and then define a transversal vector field (after this you should integrate the vector field as well).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To amplify Rene's comment, which really amounts to the answer: At each point $p$ of the submanifold $S$, the tangent space to $S$, $T_S(p)$, is a vector subspace of the tangent space to $M$, $T_M(p)$.  The quotient $T_M(p)/T_S(p)$ is the fiber $N(p)$ of the normal bundle at $p$.

Comment: Thank you. How is the quotient bundle defined? How does it get a topology and how does it become a bundle? The book doesn't say this either.

Comment: @PeterM: There is an extended explanation in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27401/defining-quotient-bundles , but the site is down at the moment.

Comment: As a space, $N$ is the disjoint union of the fibers $N(p)$. Topologize it as a quotient of $T_M$, i.e., call a subset of $N$ open iff its inverse image, under the obvious projection from $T_M(p)$ to $N$ is open in $T_M$.

Comment: Thanks. This is easy once a few details are spelled out. I can't believe I wasted a day on this. :(

Answer (score 1):

Like other have said, the fiber of the normal bundle is given by the quotient bundle ( or, just to state it, since you want to avoid this, if you have a metric, you use the orthogonal complement). For an explanation of the normal bundle see, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27401/defining-quotient-bundles . Sorry, the site

seems to be down at the moment, but hopefully will be back up soon.